# codeigniter can i stop loading header footer while displaying data in popup

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am displaying some data in popup but i don't want the header and footer there how can i achieve this in code-igniter

Note : i do not want to hide them by jQuery or CSS

This is my controller function to display data

```
function singleBookmarksView()
    {
            $web_url = $this->uri->segment(2);

            $url_split_Array = explode('-', $web_url);

            $web_id = $url_split_Array['0'];

            //print_r($url_split_Array);

            $data['singleBookmark'] = $this->bookmark_model->getSingleBookmark($web_id);
            $data['bookmarkLabels'] = $this->getBookmarkLabel();
            $this->load->view("header_view.php");
            $this->load->view("bookmark_view.php", $data);
            $this->load->view("footer_view.php");

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious, have you tried removing the header and footer view loaders?!? `$this->load->view("header_view.php");` & `$this->load->view("footer_view.php");`... If you page doesn't not load correctly without these you need to generate a new template that includes the page but with its own `<html>` & `<head>` and include all the CSS & JS.

Comment: actually if i remove the header and footer from here then data will show fine on popup but if someone try to hit the direct url then there will be no header and footer and it will not show properly

Answer (score 1):

To do this you could either

```
function singleBookmarksView()
{
        $web_url = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $url_split_Array = explode('-', $web_url);

        $web_id = $url_split_Array['0'];

        $data['singleBookmark'] = $this->bookmark_model->getSingleBookmark($web_id);
        $data['bookmarkLabels'] = $this->getBookmarkLabel();
        $this->load->view("header_view.php");
        $this->load->view("bookmark_view.php", $data);
        $this->load->view("footer_view.php");

}

//create a new route for this
function singleBookmarksViewPopup()
{
        $web_url = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $url_split_Array = explode('-', $web_url);

        $web_id = $url_split_Array['0'];

        $data['singleBookmark'] = $this->bookmark_model->getSingleBookmark($web_id);
        $data['bookmarkLabels'] = $this->getBookmarkLabel();
        $this->load->view("bookmark_view.php", $data);

}
```

Or

```
//with this method add an extra value to the URI and it 
//will show without the header and footer
function singleBookmarksView($popup = null)
{
        $web_url = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $url_split_Array = explode('-', $web_url);

        $web_id = $url_split_Array['0'];

        $data['singleBookmark'] = $this->bookmark_model->getSingleBookmark($web_id);
        $data['bookmarkLabels'] = $this->getBookmarkLabel();
        if (!$popup) {
            $this->load->view("header_view.php");
        }
        $this->load->view("bookmark_view.php", $data);
        if (!$popup) {
            $this->load->view("footer_view.php");
        }

}
```

Comment: Got the simple solution 

$this->input->is_ajax_request()

this check if request is from ajax its working anyways thanks for your efforts :)